# Plot "double" bar plots with indicating significance in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, significance

I want to plot a "double" bar chart for three categories of data, and show the significance level based on Wilcox test, for each of the two "double" bars.

Running the below code, I don't see the counts reflected on the y-axis, rather, all the bars are at the same height.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(reshape2)
theme_set(theme_pubclean())

data = data.frame("cut" = c("type 1","type 1","type 2","type 2","type 3","type 3"), "counts" = c(0.6844,0.5867,0.6297,0.6383,0.7134,0.7075), "color" = c("c","d","c","d","c","d"))
data

df <- data %>%
  filter(color %in% c("c", "d")) %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarise(counts = n()) 

ggdotchart(df, x = "cut", y ="counts",
           color = "color", palette = "jco", size = 3, 
           add = "segment", 
           add.params = list(color = "lightgray", size = 1.5),
           position = position_dodge(0.3),
           ggtheme = theme_pubclean()
)
```

The plot I'm trying to make looks something like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EndiF-sCtXFyUOAPIToRY5hqjp97b1Px

appreviate your help to:
1. edit my code such that it shows the real count values
2. add significance to the plot

Comment: Could you please make it more clear what is your expected output (with figures from your example)? Currently it's not clear where the significance comes from and how it should appear on the graph, what should happen with counts (in `data` they take continuous values, but then you use `df` where all counts are just 1), and the example has just single bars with dots while the drawn picture looks quite differently.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data %>%
  spread(color, counts) %>%
  mutate(
    lab_pos = pmax(c, d) + .07,
    lab = if_else(cut == 'type 3', '*', 'ns')
  ) %>%
  gather(color, counts, c:d) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = cut,
    y = counts,
    color = color,
    group = color
  )) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(.4),
    color = 'white',
    width = .05
  ) +
  geom_point(
    position = position_dodge(.4),
    size = 3
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
      y = lab_pos,
      label = lab
    ),
    check_overlap = TRUE,
    color = rgb(.2, .2, .2)
  ) +
  ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I need the scale on y to be from 0-1. and significance "*" or "ns" added as in the image on the drive link. Thank u!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is this enough, or you want also those buckles? :)

Comment: it does not actually calculate significance based on wilcox test. It just add those characters on top. Is there a way to compare each two "double" bars using that test, and indicate significance based on the test results? what i draw in just an example

Comment: Code provided by you does not actually calculate significance based on Wilcox test too :D
Can you show me how i can calculate it with data provided by you? ;)

Comment: You have to provide vectors of values for each group to conduct Wilcox test. If you will do it I will provide a code that will calculate significance based on Wilcox test and automatically add appropriate labels to the plot.